# Error: org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to consume a JSON and  display it in an Android listview.

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 5
    },
    "objects": [{
        "acad_rating": "4.58",
        "address": "Karawal Nagar Delhi-110094",
        "adm_close": "5/2/2016",
        "adm_open": "1/1/2016",
        "affiliated_till": "31/3/2017",
        "area": "Karawal Nagar (West)",
        "average_board_perc": null,
        "boardhighsec": "Cbse",
        "boardsec": "Cbse",
        "books_in_lib": 9684,
        "boyperc": "72.00",
        "category": " Primary With Upper Primary And Secondary And Higher Secondary(1-12) ",
        "cce_impl": true,
        "city": "Delhi",
        "cityslug": "delhi",
        "coed": "Co-Ed",
        "computer_aid_learn": true,
        "description": null,
        "district": "North East Delhi",
        "drinking_water": "Tap Water",
        "email": "bhavansl@hotmail.com",
        "facilities_rating": "5.00",
        "fax": "4132622661",
        "girlperc": "28.00",
        "good_classrooms": 21,
        "grad_teachers": "92.16",
        "highestclass": 12,
        "image": null,
        "library": true,
        "lowestclass": 1,
        "medical_checkup_last_yr": true,
        "medium": " English ",
        "mid_day_meal": "Na",
        "minage": 3,
        "name": "Sardar Patel Public Sr.Sec. School",
        "no_classrooms": 21,
        "no_computers": 35,
        "overall_rating": "4.33",
        "padmin": 15,
        "parents_smc": 2,
        "phone": "22934441",
        "pincode": 110094,
        "playground": true,
        "pqualification": "B.A., M.Phil, M.Ed.",
        "principal": "Mohd Zahid Khan",
        "pteach": 9,
        "ptotal": 24,
        "ramp": true,
        "rating": "3.5",
        "residential_school": false,
        "resource_uri": "/api/schools/7030327101/",
        "school_mgt_com": true,
        "schoolid": "7030327101",
        "schooltype": "Private Unaided School",
        "since": 1985,
        "slug": "sardar-patel-public-srsec-school",
        "student_teacher": "33.45",
        "total_seats": 0,
        "total_smc": 18,
        "total_students": 1706,
        "total_teachers": 51,
        "totalews": 0,
        "trust": "Geeta Educational Society, Shera",
        "tuition": 0,
        "website": "http://www.auroville.org.in",
        "workdays_pr": 240,
        "written_test": true,
        "zone": "4"
    }]
}
```

My Asynctask in Android:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
            String notes = jObj.getString("objects");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }
```

Not sure why I am getting error:

```
E/JSONException: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Log the value of result before you try to convert to a JSONObject

Comment: Your error says `Value http`, so you seem not to be returning the correct value from doInBackround

Comment: thanks yes that helped , I was returning the url and not the json string. Thank u !

Answer (score 1):

The String result that you are passing on to the onPostExecute() method is not a JSON string apparently.

Also, why not parse the JSON string as well within doInBackground(). The background thread is a better option to do such tasks - if possible, reserve the onPostExecute() method which runs on the UI thread for manipulations on the UI thread. And JSON parsing can definitely be done in the background.